# How to ideally create multiple apps under same project in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, project

I am working on a project which requires an admin app and a customer app. Both these apps will have many things on common like the theme, images, fonts, widgets, packages, etc. So what is the ideal way to do this?

If I create two separate projects, if there is a requirement to update the theme, I need to update it on two separate projects. How to handle the situation ideally?

Comment: Manage screen & data permissions per user type basis?

Comment: did you mean to check wheater its a user or customer and display the functionality accordingly @Nae

Comment: Yes. That's how I'd do it. But I'm unaware if there could be a better and / or simpler solution.

Comment: But a problem I encountered was that when I uploaded the app to play store it require two package names and all. So I need to change the package name which again made me change all the configuration in firebase @Nae

Comment: I don't understand. You'll have a single app. The user logs in, backend tells you the list of permitted screens & data based on whether the user is admin or customer etc.

Comment: ok..but it will increase the app size. Right?

Comment: @AbhijithK, did u find a solution?

Comment: @ymerdrengene do you have any suggestion..currently i created a library

Comment: @AbhijithK unfortuently no

Comment: @ymerdrengene I think i have found out the solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reference : https://medium.com/@iamabhijith.k/streamlining-multi-app-projects-in-flutter-the-power-of-shared-packages-28c9e577449b

The best way I have figured out is using a package. Create a flutter package with common widgets, repositories, functions, etc in the packages. Then link the package to the apps. This can be done in two main ways.

**1. Linking the package locally.**

Here the local path to the package folder is added in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  custom_package_name:
    path: path/to/package
```

This is very helpful if you are the only one working on the project. Because you don't have to publish it or push it to GitHub in order to reflect these changes in the apps that are linked to the packages

Using a relative path to the package is recommended, because if multiple teammates join the project, the absolute path may be differnt in differnt systems and leads to conflits in git. The new developers have to clone the package and the app project and arrange the package in the relative file path mentioned in the pubspec.yaml.

**2. Lining the package in remote git repo.**

Here the remote git repo link is added in pubspec.yaml.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  common_package:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/path/to/common_package.git
      ref: master
```

**ref** is the branch name refernce. Here its the master branch.
This is helpful when there is multiple developers, so that change made by everyone is updated to the remote repo and the package can be easily updated.

The developers dont need to clone the common_packages if thery are not contributing to it.

Comment: Fyi, if that helps, I've made a simple repo showcasing 2 apps using 1 shared package => https://github.com/JordanB/flutter-mono-repo

Answer (score 1):

I think the appropriate solution is to create a **package** that contains similar codes so that you can use it in both projects, If it is only about icons, themes, etc., then you should use **Flavor**, Take a look at this article https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36