# How to import flutter module to a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, module

I have a **flutter module** project and I want to import it into another **existing flutter project**, how can I do this?

I think this may not be possible since there will be two main function and don't know how they communicate.

Are there any suggestion so I can combine the these two things? I want to open the module app in another flutter app.

Comment: It's possible if the other module is created as package: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Comment: And you could technically just copy/paste everything but at the end, there's only one main.dart. The one you run with `flutter run`.

Comment: But I want to maintain the module separately from the other project, is it not possible?
If I change the module into package, the main function is a problem.

Comment: The package does not have the main function. And your app can have only one main function so you should figure out which one it is. You could, for example, call the package "main" function from the app main function if you need.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much. I seems know how to solve the problem, I will copy the main function from the package to the other project, so the routing, localization... can be set , and then I can just navigate to the home screen of the package app anytime I want. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That can work. But be aware that you cannot access anything from the other package since relation is: app has packages so sees everything from package. Package does not see the app or anything from the app package.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter yet to support this feature out of the box, see issue [#64542](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64542) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [feature request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64542) that was mentioned in above is still open, the best solution that I can think of is by merging another application to your existing flutter application by importing the application you want to merge as a [**module**](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app). Check also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67148927), where this kind of scenario was explained.

Answer (score 0):

If you merge to one flutter project as a module in another flutter project then I follow this step

1. Paste your child project which you merge in your existing project
2. Then goto your parents project pubspec.yaml file and add this as like below

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  child_project_name:
    path: ./child_project_path
```

3. After then you get the access of your child project from Parent project

Now if you also need to access Parent project from child project
Then follow the step

1. Then goto your child project pubspec.yaml file and add this as like below

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  parent_project_name:
    path: /parent_project_path
```

2. After then you get the access of your parent project from Child project

Now you can access your childProject from Parent project and parent project from child project.